# Disable taskbar (Unity Launcher) Icon combine

Tags: unity, launcher, taskbar

With Ubuntu 14.04 default desktop, when you open multiple instances of the same program, the task bar will combine them into a single icon which is very inconvenient to use. Can we disable the icon combine feature like in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in Unity. You may want to switch to another desktop environment like mate or xfce.

However it's good to know that you can switch windows inside group by using <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

Comment: Do you mean the key that contains "~"? It does not work here. I access the Ubuntu 14.04 VM remotely through VMWare Worksatio's built in VNC and OpenRealVNC client, but I don't think this will block Ctrl+`

Comment: I think you meant <Alt>+<backtick>, not <Ctrl>+<backtick>.

Comment: my mistake, I meant <Alt>+<backqoute> of course.